# Active scaffold does not populate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2.3 activescaffold, Can someone help me on how to fix this please?

When add a new controller as

```
class Admin::UserController < Admin::AdminController

  active_scaffold :User do |config|
   actions.exclude :create, :update
   config.label   = 'Users'
   form_cols = [:id, :name]
   config.columns = form_cols
   config.list.columns = form_cols
  end
end
```

It does not return any records.

Here is the log

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 0, 15
Rendering template within layouts/admin
Rendering list
Rendered _list_header (7.3ms)
Rendered _list_column_headings (4.8ms)
Rendered _messages (0.7ms)
Rendered _list_messages (5.1ms)

Rendered _list_pagination (1.0ms)
Rendered _list (14.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_header (91.3ms)
Rendered layouts/_flash (0.7ms)
```

Comment: Why are you using rails 2.3? Current version is 4.2.

Comment: it's very old product. They are running in 2.3.  Could some one please help me on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would upgrade your version of Rails and then reference the [Rails Docs regarding table migrations](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's my mistake. I have connected to the wrong DB. Hence results were not showing. when do the change in database.yaml, now fetching records.